# Modal with transparent background in react-native

Tags: android, react-native, modal-dialog, react-native-modal

How to implement a modal in App.js with background transparent.(It should show android screen in background rather than white background)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `transparent` flag to true?

```
<Modal
  transparent
  ...>
...
</Modal>
```

Reference: [Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal.html#transparent)